# Server side rendering engine application URL

Tags: sxa, jss, xm-cloud

Is there anyways I can get the ID for default internal editing host value? If i'm not wrong then when we create a project using the `XM Cloud Deploy App`, the project is set up with a default internal editing host? Such as something like these so we can set it for rendering host under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/Rendering Hosts/Default`

> 1. `https://xmc-{id}.sitecorecloud.io/`
> 2. `https://xmc-{id}:443/api/editing/render`

My question how can I find this id? So that I can update the `Server side rendering engine application URL` and `Server side rendering engine endpoint URL` value correctly. I know we have project id, environment but that seems like not related. I'm currently using `xmcloud-foundation-head` as a template, and struggling to find where is client id located at
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you create your XM Cloud environment via the app, these values are stored for you in the default predefined rendering host.

You can find that item here: `/sitecore/System/Settings/Services/Rendering Hosts/Default`. The ID that is used is unique to the rendering host created.

[image]

You should not have to do anything manually to configure this item.

Comment: Hi Richard, I created a new project using the CLI, drawing from an existing project's codebase. By doing so, the new project has inherited the identifiers from the previous one, as these were not automatically regenerated by Sitecore.
How can I have my own unique ID for the new project created by serialization?

Comment: And If I create a new fresh environment through Sitecore UI, the values from Default file is empty

Comment: @Richard where to find this ID if it was removed by mistake?

Comment: Please create new posts for additional questions.